# DirectotyNotFoundexception when i upload image through Fileupload tool in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to store the images to the ms SQL server,when i am submit the button after inserting the image i getting Directory Not Found exception  the  error.
Thanks in advance.

```
   if(filuploadimages.PostedFile!=null)
   {
                string filename = filuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
                string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filuploadimages.FileName);
                filuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Productimages/" + filename));//error

            }
```

Comment: You have to create the directory.

Comment: how??can you explain clearly?

Comment: Manually. Create the folder with that path.

Comment: I already created the productimage folder, Its show an exception error, failed to map. I am using Windows 8,is there any permission problem???

Answer (score 0):

Which path are you getting as result from this line?

```
Server.MapPath("~/Productimages/" + filename)
```

I suggest you to try to get the upload path in a different way:

```
if (filuploadimages.PostedFile != null)
{
   string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
   string uploadPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Productimages"), filename);
   filuploadimages.SaveAs(uploadPath);
}
```